# How to limit text field length in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8

How to set field limit using addAttribute function. I have:

```
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'magazine_test', array(
   'input'         => 'text',
   'type'          => 'text',
   'label'         => 'Test',
   'backend'       => '',
   'visible'       => true,
   'required'      => false,
   'user_defined'  => true,
   'visible_on_front' => true,
   'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
```

));

Is there way to write: 'length' => 10

Answer (score 3):

```
$fieldset->addField('desc', 'textarea', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Description'),
      'required'  => true,       
      'name'      => 'desc',
      'maxlength' => 50
));
```

Or Try this:

```
 $fieldset->addField('desc', 'textarea', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Description'),
      'required'  => true,       
      'name'      => 'desc',
      'after_element_html' => '<script type="text/javascript">Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {$('id_of_textarea_here').maxlength = 50})</script>'
  ))
```